# Python Syntax variable = function (variable)

Tags: python, syntax

```
x = Flatten()(vgg.output)
variable = function (variable)
```

I can't find this type of expressions in python , can anyone help me to understand the above expression

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you not understand? Also, there is no context here.

Comment: `variable = function(variable)` is a .. function call, where the result is assigned to the same variable used as an argument (evaluated to-value). In the first line, `Flatten()` is supposedly returning / might return a function (or other callable) which could subsequently be invoked - or, it might just fail if such is not returned. What does this `Flatten` come from/do? What happens when the code is run (which would require more to to even run..)?

Answer (score 1):

The `Flatten()` function here, returns another function, which takes `vgg.output` as argument. This happens because everything in python is a first class object. So you can return a function as the return value of function. This will be clear with an example:

Let's say we have a function `square` which returns the square of a number:

```
def square(number):
    return number**2
```

So calling square on a number would give:

```
>>> square(3)
9
```

Now, let us define another function that returns the `square` function, and only the function:

```
def return_func():
    return square
```

Calling `return_func` we will get the `square` function back:

```
>>> some_func = return_func()

>>> some_func
<function __main__.square(number)>

>>> some_func == square == return_func()
True
```

So calling `square(number)` should be equivalent to `return_func()(number)`, i.e.

```
>>> return_func()(3)
9
```

So in your example, `Flatten()` is equivalent to `return_func()` and `number` is equivalent to `vgg.output`.

Answer (score -1):

`x = Flattern()` is calling this function and assign returned data to `x`.

`v = function` like `v` is `function` alias. And you can do `v()` to call it.

Answer (score -1):

Python has special syntax for inner functions.

```
def Flatten()(vgg.output):
    pass
```

Is basically the same as:

```
def Flatten():
    def inner(vgg.output):
        pass
```

Comment: this is not true... for starters, `def Flatten()(vgg.output):` is a syntax error